I upgraded a C# project from .NET 4.8 to NET Core 6.0 and the serial port class has changed. using System.IO.Ports and System.IO isn't working
I upgraded a C# project from .NET 4.8 to .NET Core 6.0. The SerialPort class isn't working now. I am getting an error:

CS1069 - the type name SerialPort could not be found in the namespace "System.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffc2ddd51"

It also says I am missing the SerialPort assembly reference.
I looked up how to use the serial port in .NET 6.0 and it says to use System.IO.Ports and System.IO then SerialPort _serialPort; should work, but it doesn't recognize SerialPort.
How do I add it as an assembly reference? What is the file path where the assembly file is for .NET 6.0? I am using C# in Visual Studio 2022 Professional

Did you add the System.IO.Ports Nuget package?

I tried to install that package in the Nuget Package Manager Console but it didn't work. I have the using System.IO.Ports on the file without an error message

When I try to install in the Package manager Console I get and error ; Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Starting with .NET 5, one seldom uses Add Reference. Instead one downloads/installs the appropriate NuGet package. For example, NuGet package System.IO.Ports. Ensure you use the appropriate version for the version of .NET that you're using.

Why do you feel you need to use .NET 6.0 instead of .NET Framwork 4.8? .NET 6 will be out of support November 12, 2024 whereas .NET Framework doesn't have an end-of-support date.

It's just what they are using at my work

I installed- that same NuGet package and I keep getting an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error message

Please provide the exact version that you're using.

Create a new Windows Forms App project using the desired version of .NET , in your case, NET 6. Save the solution. Add the NuGet package System.IO.Ports with the desired version. Since you're using .NET 6, select version 6.0 for System.IO.Ports  (View => Solution Explorer. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project name and select Manage NuGet Packages... => Browse => System.IO.Ports. Select version 6.0.0. Click Install). Add using directive using System.IO.Ports;. Build and run.

Once you've accomplished this, you can write some code. If you've previously made it this far without issue, then add your code to the post.
